# Deploy VM from template with pyvmomi

Tags: vsphere, pyvmomi

I’m new to python and pyvmomi
I have task to deploy a VM machine from a template,
I looked at examples under github but couldn’t find a script that do that,

https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi
https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples

Can someone share example or reference to a guide ?

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided to the community samples has the sample you are looking for. You need to look at the [clone_vm.py](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/blob/master/samples/clone_vm.py#L47) file. There is an argument in there to allow you to set the template you are cloning from.

Comment: Thanks but doesn’t this script clone a template ( create identical template ) rather than deploy a VM from a template ?
Also looking at line 219 task = template.Clone(folder=destfolder, name=vm_name, spec=clonespec)
I couldn’t find info about .Clone ( method ? ) in documentation.

Comment: It should deploy a VM from template. As part of the clonespec, there's a property for 'template'. If you wanted a template as the end result of the clone, that template property would have to be set to true.  https://code.vmware.com/apis/196/vsphere#/doc/vim.vm.CloneSpec.html

Comment: Yes I see, I must admit I’m still confused about commands I see in examples as I can’t find them in documentation. 
I already checked vSphere API reference but for example can’t find .Clone which I mentioned before. are there docs specific for pyVmomi ?
I simply don’t know where to start.